# Match two columns and add the third column in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sum

I have generated the following table from SQL database:

```
First_User  Second_User Count
User1       NULL        427
User3       NULL        69
User2       NULL        499
User1       User1       1
User4       User2       48
User5       User2       13
```

I want to create this table from the above table:

```
User    Count
User1   429
User2   560
User3   69
User4   48
User5   13
```

Match first two column values and add the third column. I am aware to do it in python but how can I do it in SQL.

In pandas, it can be done using:

```
df = df.groupby(['User1', 'User2'])['Count'].sum().reset_index()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `UNION ALL` to combine both columns into a single column, then apply `GROUP BY` and the aggregate function `SUM()` to get the expected output:

```
SELECT User, SUM(Count) AS TOTAL
FROM (
  SELECT First_User AS User, Count
  FROM mytable
  WHERE First_User  IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Second_User, Count
  FROM mytable
  WHERE Second_User  IS NOT NULL
) AS s
GROUP BY User;
```

Result :

```
User    TOTAL
User1   429
User2   560
User3   69
User4   48
User5   13
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uYUo4GWw)

Comment: Thanks. It gives me an error that "cannot re-open the mytable" but as it was a small table so, I generated another one and applied the query on it.

Answer (score 1):

This actually requires a double aggregation union query.

```sql
SELECT User, SUM(Count) AS Count
FROM
(
    SELECT First_User AS User, SUM(Count) AS Count
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE First_User IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY First_User
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Second_User, SUM(Count)
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Second_User IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Second_User
) t
GROUP BY User
ORDER BY User;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Each half of the union aggregates by either the first or second user to get the sum of the counts (as a user might appear more than once).  The outer query then aggregates by user to find the totals.